# How to use delegate to perform callback between caller and web service helper class?

Tags: c#, web-services, delegates

I have 2 classes A and B, where they belongs to the same namespace but resides in seperate files namely a.cs and b.cs, where class B essentially is a helper wrapping a web service call as follow:

```
public class A
{
    public A() // constructor
    {
        protected static B b = new B();
    }

    private void processResult1(string result)
    {
        // come here when result is successful
    }

    private void processResult2(string result)
    {
        // come here when result is failed
    }
    static void main()
    {
        b.DoJobHelper(...);
    }
}

public class B
{
    private com.nowhere.somewebservice ws;
    public B()
    {
        this.ws = new com.nowhere.somewebservice();
        ws.JobCompleted += new JobCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
    }
    void OnCompleted(object sender, JobCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = e.Result;
        Guid taskID = (Guid)e.UserState;
        switch (s)
        {
             case "Success":
             // Call processResult1(); 
             break;
             case "Failed":
             // Call processResult2(); 
             break;
             default: break;
        }
    }
    public void DoJobHelper()
    {
        Object userState = Guid.NewGuid();
        ws.DoJob(..., userState);
    }        
}
```

**(1)** I have seen texts on the net on using delegates for callbacks but failed to apply that to my case.  All I want to do is to call the appropriate `processResult()` method upon `OnCompleted()` event, but dunno how to and where to declare the delegate:

```
public delegate void CallBack(string s);
```

**(2)** There is a sender object passed in to `OnCompleted()` but never used, did I miss anything there? Or how can I make good use of `sender`?

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: since it seems your question was answered, why don't you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
public class A
{
    public A() // constructor
    {
        protected static B b = new B(processResult1, processResult2);
    }

    private void processResult1(string result)
    {
        // come here when result is successful
    }

    private void processResult2(string result)
    {
        // come here when result is failed
    }
    static void main()
    {
        b.DoJobHelper(...);
    }
}

public class B
{
    private com.nowhere.somewebservice ws;
    private Action<string> success;
    private Action<string> failure;
    public B(Action<string> success, Action<string> failure)
    {
        this.success = success;
        this.failure = failure;
        this.ws = new com.nowhere.somewebservice();
        ws.JobCompleted += new JobCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
    }
    void OnCompleted(object sender, JobCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s;
        Guid taskID = (Guid)e.UserState;
        //this switch will never do anything because s is null right now.
        //you'll need to check some actual state, or translate some other
        //state into the "Success" and "Failure" words for the s variable
        //before you call this switch statement.
        switch (s)
        {
             case "Success":
             {    
               success(s);
               break;
             }
             case "Failed":
             {
               failure(s);
               break;
             }
             default: break;
        }
    }
    public void DoJobHelper()
    {
        Object userState = Guid.NewGuid();
        ws.DoJob(..., userState);
    }        
}
```

2) don't bother using sender. it's only important if you have more than one object's events being handled by the same event handler method.

Comment: Thanks Derick.
That'll work, but I want to try out the delegate in C#...hehe :-)

Comment: i don't understand the comment... this is valid C#... i write C# like this all day, every day

Comment: The above comment was me wondering if there is a way to apply the "delegate" construct to solve the programming problem, the only reason being to learn a new thing rather than anything else.

I'm going to use your approach since it works and get the job done.

Thanks and no offence, Derick.

Comment: System.Action<T> is a delegate. A delegate is basically an anonymous method pointer that allows you to pass a method call with the same signature as the delegate around like a variable, and call that method through the delegate. the code i wrote here is using delegates, exactly like you want. I just used a delegate that is built into the .net framework because there is no need to write your own.

Comment: if you REALLY want to write your own delegate, just add this line of code: public delegate void Action<T>(T value);

Comment: Pls accept my apologies for not knowing Action<T> is indeed a delegate, I realized that after reading up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx.
Thanks again, Derick.