# Need some help with code for getting a response from a Web service. Can you help me connect the dots?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, wsdl, web-reference

Ok, its been a while since I've worked with a Web References. I need a refresher. I think I have about 80% of the code I need to get a response going but I'm missing something. Maybe you can help me :)

**Given:**
A web method called `GetSomething` in the list of methods when pointing to a `.wsdl` url.

This produces a few classes/objects:

- `GetSomethingRequest`
- `GetSomethingCompletedEventHandler`
- `GetSomethingCompletedEventArgs`
- `myComplexType`

Which I use to create this code:

```
void someMethodToTestResponse()
{
    GetSomethingRequest request = new GetSomethingRequest();

    // fill in the request
    request.myComplexType.Property1 = "Blah";
    request.myComplexType.Property2 = "Kachoo";

    GetSomethingCompletedEventHandler handler = GetSomethingCompleted_Response;

    //.... ok now what?
    //handler.Invoke(???)
    // at this point I'm supposed to send an object for source (request maybe?)
    // and a new instance of GetSomethingCompletedEventArgs but that class is
    // asking for stuff that makes me think that is not the right idea.

}

void GetSomethingCompleted_Response(object source, GetSomethingCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // get the result
    var result = args.Result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Unless you're stuck with .NET 2.0, you should be using a Service Reference instead.

Comment: Good question, I'm using 3.5.

Comment: Then see https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: John, thats a very through post on Web services. However, The problem is that I don't have access to the web service code. I'm working in .NET 3.5 but the Classes/Types that are generated by the web service cannot be changed. So in that sense maybe I am stuck with a 2.0 way of doing this?

Comment: @John thanks your help. It was a dumb mistake that I was making. See my solution.

Comment: @DJTriple: You should still be using Service References. Microsoft considers Web References to be legacy technology. The blog post shows how to create the service only to show you how to consume one. Ignore the "create" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that I needed to find a `Service` type class. See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626577/how-to-use-delegate-to-perform-callback-between-caller-and-web-service-helper-cla) where it mentions:

```
private com.nowhere.somewebservice ws;
```

The issue was that the class they provide wasn't intellisensing for me and I figured it wasn't what I was looking for.

Here is how I would solve my problem:

```
blah.webservice.SomeMainServiceClass service = new SomeMainServiceClass();
GetSomethingRequest request = new GetSomethingRequest();

// fill in the request
request.myComplexType.Property1 = "Blah";
request.myComplexType.Property2 = "Kachoo";

object myResponse = service.GetSomething(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need web service source codes. The web service can be implemented in Java. Creating service reference woks the same, as we really don't know what is on the other side.

So, try Add Service Reference in VS2008 and enter the url to working web service. VS will examine the wsdl on server and generate needed classes for you.

From than on, you just call the service as some ordinary method call. Meaning you don't have to fiddle with requests and http and such details. All that is hidden from you. Except in app.config where many WCF settings can be changed.